# php facebook query for user subscription

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to determine if an user is subscribed to my APP, using the openGraph.

I am following what it is mentioned here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/subscriptions/tutorial#server-side

But everytime I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message '(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: v2.0https:' in /home/......
```

My code is:

```
<?php
@session_start();
ini_set('display_errors','On');

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/fb-sdk/fb-data.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/functions.inc.php');

// Facebook app settings
$app_id = FB_APPID;
$app_secret = FB_SECRET;



// Autoload the required files
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/fb-files/autoload.php' );



use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphUserPage;


// Initialize the SDK
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $app_id, $app_secret );


$session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['fb_'.FB_APPID.'_access_token']);


$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/10000********34/payment.subscriptions';

$response = (new Facebook\FacebookRequest(
    $session, 'GET', $url
))->execute();

print_r($response);
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by subscribed? do you mean have a payment subscription? if so, then as per the doc you linked to, you need to use an app access token. Moreover, your usage of the `$url` is incorrect, you should only pass the endpoint you are calling and in this case it's `/USER_ID/payment.subscriptions`

Comment: Yes, I have a payment subscription. The URL was incorrect as you said and now it works. I should've removed the "https://graph.facebook.com" part from the $url

Comment: cool, I will add this as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be passing `https://graph.facebook.com/` since [the SDK will handle this for you](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php#L52). You should only pass the endpoint you are calling: `/USER_ID/payment.subscriptions`